# fetch data from firebase swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to receive the full name from all of my users from my firebase database, and I'm currently doing something like this:

```html
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
    let friend = FriendsModel()
  
    friend.fullname = dictionary["fullname"] as! String?
    friend.email = dictionary["email"] as! String?
    friend.birthDate = dictionary["Birth date"] as! String?
                
    friend.provider = dictionary["provider"] as! String?
                
    print(friend.fullname)
  }
})
```

But postDict["fullname"] returns nil.

a picture of the firebase database:
[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3ekZ.png)

```html
func fetchUsers () {
  ref.observeSingleEvent(of:.value, with: { snapshots in
  if  snapshots.exists() {
     guard let snapshot = snapshots.children.allObjects as?    [FIRDataSnapshot] else { return }
      for eachSnap in snapshot {
        guard let eachUserDict = snapshots.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> else { return }
        // eachUserDict is an object/ dictionary representation for each user
        //this prints all the information of the users
        print (eachUserDict)
        let fullName = eachUserDict["fullname"] as? String
        //this returns nil :(
        print(fullName)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Here's a picture of what i receive:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRxSx.png)

Comment: add a picture of that from firebase

Comment: there is now a picture of the database on the post and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3ekZ.png)

Comment: are you getting `nil` for the entire object or just for the key fullName ?

Comment: the entire project

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not telling the `ref` where to observe. Change this line

```
  ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

To

```
    guard let id = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {return}
    ref.child("users").child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {  (snapshots) in
```

Updated:
 if you want to get all's full names for all users, then try this:

```
ref.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of:.value) { snapshots in 
        if  snapshots.exists() {
            guard let snapshot = snapshots.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] else { return }
     for eachSnap in snapshot {
         guard let eachUserDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> else { return }
      // eachUserDict is an object/ dictionary representation for each user
              let fullName = eachUserDict["fullName"] as? String 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i inserted the wrong code, i have updated the question, and btw my has one child (named "users") and it has 4 subclasses (fullname, email, birthdate and provider (the provider is either facebook or email)).

Comment: But that only returns the current users fullname, i what to receive all the users fullname, not only the current user. Do you know how to do that @Lamar ??

Comment: i have updated the qustion. now i get all the information from all the users, but when i try getting the name of all the users it return nil

Comment: you said you get all the info, and u said it is nil huh ?

Comment: When i print "eachUserDict" it returns the all the data about all the users, but when i print "fullname" it returns nil, you can see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRxSx.png) is what it returns in the xcode consel

Comment: it is inside another dictionary it seems